# How to understand/consume json output from PHP script

Tags: php, json, pdo

Using PHP PDO I run this query

```
SELECT Name, Latitude, Longitude, Begin, End FROM VenueData
```

And fetch the data

```
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Then output

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
print(json_encode(array('venues'=>$data)));
```

However the output is strange,

```
{"venues":[{"Name":"Flintstone1","0":"Flintstone1","Latitude":"57","1":"57","Longitude":"-124","2":"-124","Begin":"8","3":"8","End":"14","4":"14"}]}
```

It seems for every column in the select query there are 2 keys, one by name and one by index 0-n) in the json. I have not encountered this before, why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably because of the fetch you are using.

Check: [PHP Manual PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

By default this will use PDO::FETCH_BOTH which includes numerative and associate array of results.

(The fetch style options can be found here: [PHP Manual PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php))

Depending on what you want, you can either use:

```
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or:

```
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
```

By this

```
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```